# How do I make changes to :host{} styles in angular component?

Tags: html, css, angular

My goal is to change the layout of the grid on a certain button press. I've already got the method binding setup, but I'm not sure how to reference the `:host` styles. I *could* just wrap everything in a div and then reference that, but it feels sort of hack-y. How do I go about referencing the :host{} object?

**component.ts, HTML and CSS**:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent {
  editHostStyles() {
    //How do I make the reference here?
  }
}
```

```css
:host {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    row-gap: 2px;
    column-gap: 2px;
    grid-template-columns: 300px 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 300px 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<button mat-raised-button class="primary-button" (click)="editHostStyles()">Update Style!</button>
```

Comment: Isn't ```viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef``` you are looking for?

Comment: I dit not understand the question so I try as a comment : inject the `elementRef: ElementRef` in the constructor and get `this.elementRef.nativeElement` then do whatever you want to its style.

Comment: Also, this might help (use `@HostBinding`, this is cleaner imho): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44122081/how-to-dynamically-change-css-in-host-in-angular-2

Comment: You can use Renderer2 or a @HostBinding annotation to access or modify an element's style rather than using an ElementRef's native element. Modifying a nativeElement is not recommended https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef#properties